# Create Custom Wordpress Login Credentials Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am have a membership directory for physicians using gravity forms for the registration page and gravity view to display the members in the directory..

The site owner informed me after-the-fact that the login credentials are to be set to specific unique criteria that are specific to each member..

For example the username is to be that individuals members license number and the password is to be the last name of the member..

Is there a way to run a script that will automatically update all of the usernames and passwords for the existing members? Keep in mind that there are over 900 active members in this directory. Or am I going to have to manually update all of the usernames and passwords in the database?

Comment: Haw are the `username` and `password` stored? In a database? Which database? If SQL it is simple to write out a query that will update all the `username`'s and `password`'s, we would need information on the structure of the DB and the names of the tables involved and connecting Id's for joins if there need to be any.

Comment: Its SQL DB.. should have added that in the original question

Comment: Seems like last name for the username and license number for the password would make more sense.

Comment: So the existing list of usernames / passwords are in a different SQL DB or in the same one as WordPress? Also, do I understand correctly that there is data in a non-WordPress format and you need to turn that data into WordPress users?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a script in SSMS then to update all the `username` and `password` pairs. Maybe something like this:

```
update dbo.Users
set Password = LastName,UserName = LicenseNumber
from dbo.User 
where LastName is not null and LicenseNumber is not null
```

Obviously, I cannot test this as I don't know the structure of your DB or the names of the tables involved. If there are more than one table and you have to join them it could look like this:

```
update dbo.UserData
set UD.Password = U.LastNamen UD.UserName = U.LicenseNumber
from dbo.UserData UD
LEFT JOIN dbo.User U on U.Id = UD.UserID
where U.LicenseNumber is not null and U.LastName is not null
```

I am using the `not null` for both the LicenseNumber and LastName since the user will need both to have a username and password set by this script.

If you provide more information I could give a more specific answer.

Comment: It is not advisable to make edits directly to the database if it's possible to use an existing wordpress function for the same task.

Comment: OP says that they are already in the DB, it is much simpler to update the DB then use an API from a third party to do the same thing.

Comment: The wordpress wp_create_user function and wp_insert_user https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/user.php#L1401 will do a whole lot of things the make sure the users are created in a secure way that won't break your wordpress site. Checks to see if an identical user exists, adds slashes for usernames like "Jim P. O'Malley", sanitizes input. It also hashes the passwords correctly for insertion into the database. Why re-write all this code yourself when it already exists in the wordpress core?

Comment: Also, it's not 3rd party to use WordPress code to make WordPress users.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`wp_create_user` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user):

```
<?php
    // make an array of all the users you want to add
    $allusers = array();

    $allusers[0]['username'] = 'sally_sparrow';
    $allusers[0]['email'] = 'sally@example.com';
    $allusers[0]['password'] = '26aWpfRFcNhcZjBLLj3d';

    $allusers[1]['username'] = 'sam_smith';
    $allusers[1]['email'] = 'sam@example.com';
    $allusers[1]['password'] = '9VF4qTXLhTJdCWzbbL9s';

    // etc...    

    foreach ($allusers as $user) {
        $result = wp_create_user( $user['username'], $user['password'], $user['email'] );
        if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            echo '<div class="error notice">' . $return->get_error_message() . '</div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="updated notice">Added user id #' . $result . '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```